# How to have a global variable coming from db in symfony template?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, twig-extension

How can I have a global variable in symfony template?
I did read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html)
but I prefer to fetch parameter from database, I think this service will be loaded on startup before it can fetch anything from db. Is it possible to do a trick to do so?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**EDIT: Update in 2019 with Symfony 3.4+ syntax.**

Create a Twig extension where you inject the Entity Manager:

<kbd>Fuz/AppBundle/Twig/Extension/DatabaseGlobalsExtension.php</kbd>

```
<?php

namespace Fuz\AppBundle\Twig\Extension;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\Extension\GlobalsInterface;

class DatabaseGlobalsExtension extends AbstractExtension implements GlobalsInterface
{

   protected $em;

   public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
   {
      $this->em = $em;
   }

   public function getGlobals()
   {
      return [
          'myVariable' => $this->em->getRepository(FuzAppBundle\Entity::class)->getSomeData(),
      ];
   }
}
```

Register your extension in your <kbd>Fuz/AppBundle/Resources/config/services.yml</kbd>:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true 

    Fuz\AppBundle\Twig\Extension\DatabaseGlobalsExtension: ~
```

Now you can do the requests you want using the entity manager.

Don't forget to replace paths and namespaces to match with your application.

Answer (score 3):

As of this day, the class signature has changed. You must implement \ Twig_Extension_GlobalsInterface, without it, your globals won't show up.

```
class MyTwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension implements Twig_Extension_GlobalsInterface
{ }
```

Bye!

Answer (score 2):

you can register a twig extension

```
services:
    twig_extension:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Extension\TwigExtension
        arguments: [@doctrine]
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

And then in the TwigExtension you can do as follows:

```
class TwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getGlobals() {
        return array(
            // your key => values to make global
        );
    }
}
```

So you could get a value from the database in this TwigExtension and pass it to the template with the getGlobals() function

Answer (score 2):

Stay away from [global variables.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil)

Instead make a custom twig extension then inject the database connection as a parameter.

Something like:

```
services:
    acme.twig.acme_extension:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\AcmeExtension
        arguments: [@doctrine.dbal.default_connection]
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

Details:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html